# binary operator expected while checking for multiple file existed in directory

Tags: file, unix, directory

I'm new to unix.

I'm checking for multiple files in a directory

```
[ [ -s file1 ] && [ -s file2 ] ] && echo "File exist" || echo "Not exist"
```

I'm getting the error **binary operator expected**

I had tried  this also

```
[ [ -s file1 ]&&[ -s file2 ] ] && echo "File exist" || echo "Not exist"
```

Comment: I suppose you can't do something like " .... && echo ..." becaus **echo** is not a binary operator. Try something like *if [ [ -s $file1 ] && [ -s $file2 ] ]; then echo ... ; else echo ....; fi*

Answer (score 0):

You have one too many sets of braces. Should be:

```
[ -s file1 ] && [ -s file2 ] && echo "File exist" || echo "Not exist"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
[[ -s file1 ]] && [[ -s file2 ]] && echo "File exist" || echo "Not exist"
```